# Render plt.vlines(...) in plt.xkcd() mode as all other lines

Tags: matplotlib

[image: my plot]

As you can see from the image above a `plt.vlines()` is rendered as a straight line, while everyone desires a wobbling(?) line.

My code:

```
# usual imports
with plt.xkcd():
   ...
   plt.vlines(t0, -0.04, 1.04)
  ...
```

A definite and motivated *"IT'S IMPOSSIBLE"* answer would be gladly accepted. OTOH I won't accept an answer that fakes `plt.vlines()` using a grid.  I know how to do it and I've asked a different question.

Comment: I don't appear to be able to get `ax.vlines` to work, but `ax.axvline` will. I know that's not quite the same, but might help you. You might also look into setting the `sketch_params` for the `LineCollection` returned by `vlines`

Comment: I totally forgot `ax.axvline`! thank you very much.  OTOH, I've tried already (just a dozen of minutes ago) to use `vls.set_sketch_params(...)` but it doesn't work... I suspect that the lines in the collection are rendered bypassing the sketch parameters.  Does the same happen for the axes ticks?

Comment: In my (new and better) understanding, `vlines` is oriented to plot a somehow large collection of vertical lines in the most efficient manner (as a collection, they are rendered at once if I've understood the logic behind collections).  For my use case it is better to use `axvline` or even `def myvline( x, yo, y1, **kw): ...` — If someone will come and explain how comes that collections cannot support the sketch parameters, I'll still be happy to accept their answer.

Comment: OK, glad that'll work for you. Sorry I don't know the answer about the LineCollection and sketch_params